# Perl threads, sockets and STDIN interference

Tags: multithreading, perl, sockets, stdin

I am trying to use a perl threads and sockets, to create a simple client/server application. The problem comes in client side, when trying to mix STDIN with socket reading in different threads. Note, I succeeded with using Tkx as workaround to STDIN. But my intention is to build short samples for teaching purposes only, in several programming languages. I intend to create the program minimal, with no UI, as simple as possible.
Here is the code of client, which has the problems:

```perl
use strict;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use threads;

our $sock = new IO::Socket::INET ( PeerAddr => 'localhost', PeerPort => 1234, Proto => 'tcp') or die "cannot connect to localhost";
my $thr = threads->create(\&msg_proc, $sock); #, $sock);

for (my $msg; $msg ne "exit";)
{
   $msg = <STDIN>;
   $msg =~ s/[\r\n\s\0]*\Z//g;
   $sock->send ("$msg\n");# or die "can't send";
};
$sock->close();
print "exit main thread\n";

$thr->join() if $thr->is_running();
print "exit all\n";

sub msg_proc
{
   my $svr = shift;
   my $i = 0;
   while ($svr)
   {
      sleep(1);
      $svr->send  ("{slept $i}\n") or die "server closed connection";
      my $svr_msg = <$svr> or die "server closed connection";

      $svr_msg =~ s/[\r\n\s\0]*\Z//g;
      print "From server: <<$i $svr_msg>>\n";

      $i++;
   }
   print "sock exit\n";
}
```

The problem starts when I remove the line `$svr->send` in the thread procedure `msg_proc`. In this case the client fails to read normally from STDIN, looks like interfering with socket reading operation `<$svr>`. Looks like it interferes with `<STDIN>` operation. For some reason these two can't coexist in parallel. Note, the C++ and Java versions of these demos do not have this problem.

This is the code of the server:

```perl
use strict;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use threads;

my $sock = IO::Socket::INET -> new (LocalPort => 1234, Proto => 'tcp', Listen => 1, Reuse => 1) or die  "Could not create socket: $!\n";
print "server started\n";

my $i = 0;
while (my $s = $sock->accept())
{
   print "New connection\n";
   my $thr = threads->create(\&client_proc, $s, $i);
   $s->send("welcome $i\n");
   $i++;
}

sub client_proc
{
   my $client = shift;
   my $client_no = shift;
   print "## client $client_no started\n";
   $client->send("hello $client_no\n");
   for (my $msg; $msg ne "exit";)
   {
      $msg = <$client> or die "client $client_no closed connection";
      $msg =~ s/[\r\n\s\0]*\Z//;
      print "From client $client_no: '$msg' len: ", length ($msg), "\n";
      $client->send( "client $client_no: $msg\n" ) or die "client $client_no closed connection";
   };
   $client->close();
   print "## client $i exit\n";
}
```

As I understand from [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads), the use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged. But I can't understand, what **interpreter-based threads** actually means, and what is exactly the alternative provided. Does this mean using threads is discouraged in perl at all?
Note: I am using Strawberry Perl 5.32.1 64 bit under Windows 11, zip package, no msi. But under ActiveState Perl the problem was identically the same.

Comment: Re "*the use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged*", They are supported. Bugs relating to threads have received the proper attention. So I have previously asked p5p (the Perl dev team) what that means. I didn't really get an answer. All I really got was that "threads are hard, so don't use threads", and/or that people on the #perl IRC channel were tired of answering thread questions.

Comment: Since Perl 5.8, thread programming has been available using a model called interpreter threads which provides a new Perl interpreter for each thread, and, by default, results in no data or state information being shared between threads. https://perldoc.perl.org/threads#DESCRIPTION

Comment: Tip: `$thr->join() if $thr->is_running();` should be `$thr->join();`. Think of `join` as `waitpid` for threads.

Comment: I can't explain the behaviour.

Comment: @gapsf by the way, just curious. Have you tried and see if your suggestion has any effects?